No PyQt6 version found through pip
I am trying to install PyQt6 in a conda environment for cellpose[gui].
Running `pip install pyqt6` gives the following error:
Collecting pyqt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.7.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/u/home/u/user/miniconda3/envs/cellpose-gui/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/u/home/u/user/miniconda3/envs/cellpose-gui/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/u/home/u/user/miniconda3/envs/cellpose-gui/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 587, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "project.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 59, in apply_user_defaults
          self._get_qt_configuration()
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 478, in _get_qt_configuration
          for line in project.read_command_pipe([self.qmake, '-query']):
        File "/work/tmp/pip-build-env-g161zev3/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 554, in read_command_pipe
          raise UserException(
      sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Specifying a specific version e.x. pip install pyqt6==6.2.1 gives the error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt6-Qt6>=6.2.1 (from pyqt6) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt6-Qt6>=6.2.1

This is what my environment looks like (Python 3.8.5 and pip 24.0):
  - numpy==1.24.4
  - nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.20.5
  - packaging==24.0
  - proto-plus==1.23.0
  - protobuf==4.25.3
  - pyasn1==0.6.0
  - pyasn1-modules==0.4.0
  - pyqt5==5.15.10
  - pyqt5-qt5==5.15.2
  - pyqt5-sip==12.13.0
  - pyqtgraph==0.13.3
  - qtpy==2.4.1
  - requests==2.31.0
  - rsa==4.9
  - scipy==1.10.1
  - sympy==1.12
  - tifffile==2023.7.10
  - torch==2.3.0
  - tqdm==4.66.4
  - triton==2.3.0
  - urllib3==2.2.1
  - zipp==3.18.1

Does this mean that pip cannot find a PyQt6 version? If so, how can I fix this?
Note: I am able to install PyQt5.
